# Using a DTO throws a 500 validation exception

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Following the documentation [How to Use a DTO for Writing](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#how-to-use-a-dto-for-writing), I'm getting a 500 validation error:

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/Error",
    "@type": "hydra:Error",
    "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
    "hydra:description": "Cannot validate values of type \"NULL\" automatically. Please provide a constraint.",
    ...
```

The DTO is the same as documented (note the specific namespace):

```
namespace Acme\Infrastructure\Dto;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "post"={
 *              "path"="/do-something",
 *          },
 *      },
 *      itemOperations={},
 * )
 */
final class DoSomethingRequest
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    public $email;
}
```

Here's the configuration:

```
# api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    mapping:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Infrastructure/Dto'
```

Comment: Is your top level namespace really `Acme`?

Comment: Yes, the namespace has been changed from the default one to the name of the organization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was calling the endpoint sending `FormData` encoded payload. It turns out that "API Platform only supports raw documents as request input" (cf. https://api-platform.com/docs/core/form-data/).

Nevertheless, I believe that would be nice to throw a more explicit exception in this case than letting the `RecursiveContextualValidator` of Symfony handle the case with an obscure message.